# Does Meghan Markle need to pay taxes for her stay at a billionaires house?

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, irs, gift-tax

According to reports, Meghan Markle is receiving free accommodations at the home of a Canadian businessman.

Assuming this is true, and given Meghan is a US citizen, and considering the fair market value of staying in such a residence could be thousands of dollars per night would Meghan be responsible for taxes to the IRS and CRA?

Comment: The NY Post has been a rag for decades and in recent years it has deteriorated from that 'standard' :->)

Comment: If it applies to Markle, why wouldn't it apply to the rest of us, as for instance when I visit friends and stay overnight?  There's also the question of exactly how you would value such a stay, if the owner of the house doesn't regularly rent out rooms.

Comment: The reason I thought it might be unique in this situation is because the value of the stay is certainly in the tens of thousands of dollars - equivalent to more than the gift tax maximum

Comment: @CodyBugstein: Why, in your opinion, is the value of the stay "certainly in the tens of thousands of dollars"?  I doubt the homeowner is renting out rooms on AirBnB, so there's no comparable price data.  The homeowner has sunk costs for maintaining the house whether anyone stays there or not, so (unless they trash the place) the marginal costs of guests is maybe a bit of extra food & utility use.

Comment: That's ridiculous. It's obvious that the value of staying at such property is AT LEAST at par with a luxury hotel. When Nikki Haley took a private flight as a gift,  prominent govt watchdog groups argued she should have valued the flights at the rate of private jet rentals and not of commercial airline seats. I see this as very similar

Comment: @CodyBugstein: No, it's not obvious at all.  Citing those watchdog groups as "evidence" doesn't help, because they're wrong :-)

Comment: If yes, it should apply to Nigel Farage as well.

Comment: The issue with Nikki Haley was the gift being to a government official, and nothing to do with tax.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the US the giver of gifts has the gift-tax obligation if any exists, not the recipient. Even if letting them stay at the house was considered to be a gift it wouldn't be relevant to the IRS if the giver is Canadian.

I'm not familiar with gift-taxation in Canada.

Comment: This is a good and correct answer, but the answer by @DJClayworth has the relevant Canadian information also.

Answer (score 17):

Canadian tax law is much simpler than the US. [Canada does not have a "gift tax"](https://turbotax.intuit.ca/tips/tax-tip-if-i-give-cash-to-my-kids-is-it-tax-deductible-in-canada-5081) either for the giver or the receiver, except for some very special cases.

US gift tax is paid by the giver, not the receiver, so would not be payable by a Canadian on a gift given in Canada.